# Is it right use-case of KSql

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am using KStreams where I need to de-duplicate the data. Source ingests duplicated data due to many reasons i.e data itself duplicate, re-partitioning.

Currently using Redis for this use-case where data is stored something as below

```
id#object list-of-applications-processed-this-id-and-this-object
```

As KSQL is implemented on top of RocksDB which is also a Key-Value database, can I use KSql for this use case?

At the time of successful processing, I would add an entry to KSQL. At the time of reception, I will have to check the existence of the id in KSQL.

Is it correct use case as per KSql design in the event processing world?

Comment: I guess the question is, what you exactly want to do... For example, do you want to de-duplicate the STREAM a write the result into an output topic?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I will have to decide whether I should process that event or just discard it I e sending to another topic. It's not deduplicating the stream. It's using ksql DB as a cache. I have application written in Kstreams. In that application, I would like to have a check after receiving the event. Check in the sense whether that event already occurred in the past. Here can I use ksql DB? How a memcache or redis or even mongodb would be used. Similar way KSql.As I have confluent subscription,I don't want to go for another license for this use case.I read that ksqldb could be used as cache

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use to use ksqlDB as a cache, you can create a `TABLE` using the topic as data source. Note that a `CREATE TABLE` statement by itself, does only declare a schema (it does not pull in any data into ksqlDB yet).

```sql
CREATE TABLE inputTable <schemaDefinition> WITH(kafka_topic='...');
```

Check out the docs for more details: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/create-table/

To pull in the data, you can create a second table via:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cache AS SELECT * FROM inputTable;
```

This will run a query in the background, that read the input data and puts the result into the ksqlDB server. Because the query is a simple `SELECT *` it effectively pulls in all data from the topic. You can now issue "pull queries" (i.e, lookups) against the result to use TABLE `cache` as desired: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/select-pull-query/

**Future work:**

We are currently working on adding "source tables" (cf https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/7474) that will make this setup simpler. If you declare a source table, you can do the same with a single statement instead of two:

```sql
CREATE SOURCE TABLE cache <schemaDefinition> WITH(kafka_topic='...');
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, I will try it out definitely and let you know soon on the performance.